# Defining Array.prototype.search Causing Issue with Regex .match

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Defining Array.prototype search (see code below) causes error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Code:

```
Array.prototype.search = function(key, prop){
    for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i][prop] === key) {
            return this[i];
        }
    }
}
var xml = {};
xml.answer = {};
xml.answer[0] = {};
xml.answer[0].default = "hello";

var match = xml.answer[0].default.match(/\(\d+\-\d+\)\s*$/);
```

Any idea why extending Array.prototype causes .match to stop working?

Comment: Works just fine for me, other than the regex not matching anything, which is expected ?

Comment: It's expected but I'm getting a value of search for xml.answer[0].default

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, `xml.answer[0].default` is clearly defined, and the `prototype.search` code above it has nothing to do with that ?

Comment: Try `[1,2,3].search(function(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b)
})`

Comment: This code gives me no error, and `match === null`. In which line of your code do you get the error?